# Android External Storage is not synchronized

Tags: android, android-image, navigation-drawer, android-external-storage, android-navigationview

I am trying to update a user profile photo in the settings activity. During that I want to update the photo in the external storage too.

```
if (checkExternalStorage()) {
        File filePath = context.getExternalCacheDir();
        File myDir = new File(filePath.getAbsolutePath() + path);
        myDir.mkdirs();
        File file = new File(myDir, fileName);
        if (file.exists()) file.delete();
        try {
            FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);
            finalBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, out);
            out.flush();
            out.close();
            Log.d(TAG, "File at path " + myDir.getAbsolutePath() + " was saved");

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Unsuccessful storing image in SD card " + e.getMessage());
        }

    }
```

I saved the photo successfully in external storage. After that I would like to update the profile photo in the Navigation drawer by this line of code calling in the lifecycle onResume.

```
File filePath = getExternalCacheDir();
        File myDir = new File(filePath.getAbsolutePath() + STORAGE_IMAGES_PATH + STORAGE_MY_PROFILE_PHOTO);
        if (ImageUtils.checkExternalStorage() && myDir.exists()) {
            Picasso.with(this).load(myDir).into(profilePhoto);
        }
```

But the photo in the Navigation drawer is only updated when I restart the app. If I open a folder with my saved images on my device, the photo is up-date Do you know where it could be problem?

Comment: Not sure if Picasso caches the images so if you're overwriting the original image then perhaps it's returning the cached image?

Comment: give a constant name to your profile picture for that application and on  drawer open set image in imageView

Comment: "After that I would like to update the profile photo in the Navigation drawer" -- use `finalBitmap` for that. Why would you re-load the image from disk? Beyond that, call `out.getFD().sync()` between `flush()` and `close()`, and see what you might need to do to force Picasso to reload it rather than relying on a cache.

Comment: I want to reload only when the user has changed his photo

Comment: It was caused by Picasso which had cached those images. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I solved by this line of code.

```
 File filePath = getExternalCacheDir();
                File myDir = new File(filePath.getAbsolutePath() + STORAGE_IMAGES_PATH + STORAGE_MY_PROFILE_PHOTO);
                Picasso.with(this).invalidate(myDir);
```